# Other documents features than tf-idf for clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, information-retrieval

What are other feature representations for documents that are used for clustering textual documents? The only representation I'm aware of is tf-idf. Are there other ones?

Comment: This question is not a programming question and would better be suited for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a weighting (or an extreme version of it) but I noticed that trimming frequent features makes document clustering with k-means much more stable: for instance you can try to trim all features that are non-zero for 50% of the documents or more.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean, can you please give an example?

Comment: Count the document frequency for each feature (as you do to compute the IDF of TF-IDF) and zero out or remove all features with `df > 0.5`.